# pine script newby - in TV, cannot trigger short strategy exits, longs ok

Tags: pine-script

My short side exit/close trades do not trigger, however the proper conditions are recognized (proven by bg color code).
I left out lengthy date filter and macd inputs for brevity..

````
if (datesok and crossover(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("MacdLE", strategy.long, comment="L")
if (datesok and crossunder(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("MacdSE", strategy.short, comment="S")
longstate =delta>0
shortstate =delta<0
exitLong = longstate and crossover (delta, (atr(14)*myATR))
exitShort = shortstate and crossunder (delta, (-1*(atr(14)*myATR)))
if (datesok and exitLong)
    strategy.cancel_all()
    strategy.close("MacdLE",strategy.long, comment="Lx")
if (datesok and exitShort)
    strategy.cancel_all()    
    strategy.close("MacdSE",strategy.short, comment="Sx")
bgcolor( longstate ? color.yellow : na )    
bgcolor( shortstate ? color.blue : na )
bgcolor( exitLong ? color.green : na )
bgcolor( exitShort ? color.red : na )
if (not datesok)
    strategy.close_all()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Technically `strategy.long` is boolean true and `strategy.short` false. They aren't required for `strategy.close()`. So when you call strategy.close() for your short position you are telling it to never close.

It should look like this :

```
if (datesok and exitLong)
    strategy.cancel_all()
    strategy.close("MacdLE", comment="Lx")
if (datesok and exitShort)
    strategy.cancel_all()    
    strategy.close("MacdSE", comment="Sx")
```

Comment: this solved my issue, thank you @rumpypumpydumpy